# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a **react-native** app with **typescript** that is **not using Expo**. When running in iOS I get the below error after the splash screen. I understand this might be related to the fact that `react-navigation` is using `react-native-gesture-handler` but that is also included and linked in my app. It also might be because of missing typescript types but adding `@types/react-navigation` didn't help either.

```
[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')

This error is located at:
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Transitioner.js:215)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.tsx:69)
    in Provider (at App.tsx:68)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

I have tried react-native link, cleaning react native cache, deleting node_modules folder and re-installing, cleaning the npm cache, re-installing the application from scratch, resetting the iOS Simulator contents.

Below is my package.json for reference:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^2.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "base64-js": "^1.3.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.2",
    "firebase-nest": "^0.7.1",
    "i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "jsc-android": "^236355.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mobx": "^5.6.0",
    "mobx-firebase-store": "^1.2.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.3.6",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-track-player": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.24",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.36",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.16.0",
    "tslint-config-standard": "^8.0.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
```

Also my babelrc content here:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "mobx"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I got it working by installing these devDependencies:
`"@babel/core": "^7.3.4", "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.3.4"` 
and by adding this line to babel.config.js: 
`plugins: [['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'], ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {'loose': true}]]`

Comment: I got to admit, using the latest versions of react native and it's dependencies is a bad idea. for other problems I found, I reverted everything to react native 57. Too many bugs!!

Comment: Update: this issue completely went away once I updated to RN 59 and then 60

Answer (score 10):

Try adding `@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` to your `babel.config.js`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "mobx"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

see https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5825 and https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8417

Comment: This solution worked for me. I did not include the "mobx" preset, otherwise my babel config is as above.

One important detail is the order of the plugins. @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types needs to be the first.

I'm on RN@0.63.4, RNN@7.11.3, mobx@3.6.2, mobx-react@4.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Those who not solved this issue. Try to run react-native start in terminal before react-native run-android or ios. In my case it was all about node js window

Answer (score 0):

For those who couldn't solve this issue using above solutions, you can try:

`expo start -c`

according to this github issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6154